# “Scribble me a line” does that sound rude?

Tags: word-usage, phrases, idioms

I’ve been using this construction for quite a long time, while giving anybody my contacts in the informal situations, meaning “write me if you have time and inspiration” and I have no idea where I caught it. Recently I’ve been talking to a person from USA and used the phrase, and I was told it sounds very peculiar. He never heard it and found it really strange and funny :) So obviously I googled it and found out that the proper idiom is “drop somebody a line”. English isn’t my native language. My mistake, though word “scribble” does have the meaning “to write, not putting much effort in it”. But what shade of “not putting effort” does it have? I now, feel like I’ve been rude to people by using it, cause the word “scribble” may have some negative connotations? Like associate with clumsy and untidy? I shall not use it anymore but I'd like to know how grievous the mistake was :) So my questions are to native speakers: have you ever heard this construction, can it exist and what feeling does this phrase give you? Thank you in advance!

Comment: "Scribble" does have an aspect of carelessness to it. "Drop me a line" seems more idiomatic.(AmE speaker here.)

Comment: We have standard phrases for a reason: to avoid misunderstandings and comply with etiquette. Anything other than that sounds like either non-native, or idiolect.

Comment: I don't find it rude, given the context. It merely sounds informal and, to me somewhat friendly. I would choose my audience for using it -someone I knew well - but I have, in the past said such things as "Can you scribble your ideas down and we'll have a look at them tomorrow." **OED**  has **to scribble down: [...] to note or jot down quickly.** 1831 *I have scribbled down all I can recollect of a very loose conversation.* but "down is not always included.

Comment: @rajah9 "Drop me a line" is normal BrEng as well. I don't know where the OP got "scribble me a line" from unless it's from "scribble some ideas down" or "scribble some notes down" both of which are used. It's worth noting that "Drop me an email (or text)" is used sometimes as well. I don't think the OP will have upset anyone though, just made them pause for a second or two.